# SQLite Update or overwrite duplicates

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, insert

Here is how I create the table:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Campaigns (
            day text,
            firstname text,
            lastname, text)""")
```

Here is my sqlite insert method:

```
def insert_campaign(Day, FirstName, LastName):
        with conn:
                c.execute("INSERT INTO Campaigns VALUES (:day, :firstname, :lastname)", 
                {'day':Day,'firstname':FirstName, 'lastname':LastName})
```

What I want is for this insert function to overwrite existing records.

For example if I already inserted:

```
3/25/2019 | John | Doe
3/26/2019 | Jane | Doe
3/27/2019 | Bob | Dylan
```

And I want to insert:

```
3/26/2019 | Jane | Doe
3/27/2019 | Bob | Dylan
3/28/2019 | Greg | Rogers
```

I want the result to be:

```
3/25/2019 | John | Doe
3/26/2019 | Jane | Doe
3/27/2019 | Bob | Dylan
3/28/2019 | Greg | Rogers
```

Right now it is adding everything, resulting in 6 rows, with duplicates.

Comment: You need a unique key/index or primary key (same thing in most cases in sqlite) so that duplicates can be found (maybe on `(firstname, lastname)`, and then use `INSERT OR REPLACE` or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you do not want duplicates, you need to define the combination of all three columns as a unique or primay key:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Campaigns (
            day TEXT NOT NULL,
            firstname TEXT NOT NULL,
            lastname TEXT NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (day, firstname, lastname))""")
```

Then, you could use the [`replace`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-statement/) statement:

```
def insert_campaign(Day, FirstName, LastName):
    with conn:
            c.execute("REPLACE INTO Campaigns VALUES (:day, :firstname, :lastname)", 
            {'day':Day,'firstname':FirstName, 'lastname':LastName})
```

Comment: `day` is not unique, the only unique should be all 3 fields exactly. I should be able to add `3/27/2019 | Bob | Dylan` and `3/28/2019 | Bob | Dylan`. Is there a way to make all the columns together as a primary key?

Comment: @crystyxn my apologies, I misread the question. You should define the combination of all three columns as a key - see my edited answer.